# curl request says to address needs to be an array when it already is?

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to send an email out using Mandrill by adapting the curl command from https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-new-message/ and using the API key from https://us1.admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/ and I'm getting an error that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Here's the command I'm running:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send \
  -d '{"key":"...","message":{"html":"hello, world!","subject":"hello, world!","from_email":"neubert@neubert.com","to":["neubert@neubert.com"]}}'
```

Here's the response:

```
{"status":"error","code":-2,"name":"ValidationError","message":"Validation error: {\"message\":{\"to\":[\"Please enter an array\"]}}"}
```

Here it is decoded:

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "code": -2,
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "message": "Validation error: {\"message\":{\"to\":[\"Please enter an array\"]}}"
}
```

I don't understand. "to" is an array...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also got the same error at first then going through the [documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-new-message/) keenly, I noticed that the `to` field in `message` is **NOT** a list of email addresses. I know it's intuitive that way!!

**It's a list of object's with 3 fields: email, name and type.**

An ideal JSON Body will be as follows:

```
{    
    "key": "<YOUR_MANDRILL_API_KEY>", # Caution! It is not a mailchimp API key
    "message": {
        "html": "testing html part",
        "text": "testing text part",
        "subject": "testing subject",
        "from_email": "<FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS>",
        "from_name": "<FROM_NAME>",
        "to": [
            # Recipient 1 
            {
                "email": "<Recipient1_EMAIL_ADDRESS>",
                "name": "<Recipient1_NAME>"
            },
            # Recipient 2 
            {
                "email": "<Recipient2_EMAIL_ADDRESS>",
                "name": "<Recipient2_NAME>"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```